# Files with same name placed incorrectly in General Tree

Tags: java

I'm working on a `FileSystem` implementation of General Tree. I've ran into the problem that multiple files with the same name intended for different places in the `FileSystem` are created, but then inserted incorrectly.

I create my directories with the `mkdir` method. Here is how I input it in my main class:

```
if (userInput[0].equals("mkdir")) {
            if (userInput[1].equals("-p")) {
                // This portion of code will check if the path of
                // directories provided have been created, if not, create
                // them.
                String[] dirSplit = userInput[2].split("/");
                int size = dirSplit.length;
                Directory saveWDir = tree.getWDir();

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if (tree.isFile(dirSplit[i])) {
                        tree.setWDir((Directory) tree.findFile(tree.getRoot(), dirSplit[i]));
                    } else {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            tree.mkdir(dirSplit[i]);
                        } else {
                            tree.setWDir((Directory) tree.findFile(tree.getRoot(), dirSplit[i - 1]));
                            tree.mkdir(dirSplit[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                tree.setWDir(saveWDir);

            } else if (userInput[1].contains("/")) {
                // This portion of code will create a directory farther down
                // the tree
                // like creating c in a/b/c
                String[] dirSplit = userInput[1].split("/");
                int size = dirSplit.length;
                int count = 0;
                Directory saveWDir = tree.getWDir();

                // Goes through the user input checking if the files are
                // there until the last index of the array
                for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
                    if (tree.isFile(dirSplit[i])) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if (count == size - 1) {
                    tree.setWDir((Directory) tree.findFile(tree.getRoot(), dirSplit[size - 2]));
                    tree.mkdir(dirSplit[size - 1]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(
                            "mkdir: cannot create directory '" + userInput[1] + "' No such file or directory.");
                }

                tree.setWDir(saveWDir);

            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i < userInput.length; i++) {
                    tree.mkdir(userInput[i]);
                }
            }

        }
```

My `findFile` method is a preorderd recursive method that finds the file through their name.

`wDir` is my current working directory.

The root will always be `/`. As an example of my problem.

```
         "/"
        /
       a
      /
     b
    /
   c
```

To do this in my program right after it starts you would enter:

`mkdir -p a/b/c`

Now say I would like to create a child of the root named `b` as well. I enter:

`mkdir -p b/d/e`

Instead of creating a tree with the structure of:

```
          /
        /  \
       a     b
      /       \
     b          d
    /            \  
   c               e
```

The tree will have the structure:

```
          /
        /  
       a     
      /       
     b         
    / \            
   c   d 
         \
           e
```

Some additional things, I do have a method `getPath()` that returns a String in my `File` class.

An example of my `getPath()` method. Lets say I have the general tree I created above. With `/`'s child being `a`, `a`'s child being `b`, and `b`'s child being `c`.

Getting the path of `c` would return `/a/b/c`.

There are 2 classes that inherit the `File` class, which are `Directory` and `TextFile`.

Currently my `mkdir` method is structured this way because I've handled most everything else in the main class.

```
public void mkdir(String path) {
    files.add(new Directory(path));

    int size = files.size();

    // Sets the parent
    files.get(size - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Sets the child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(size - 1));
}
```

Any other info you guys need just let me know and I'll happily provide it.

EDIT: As requested, here is the structure of my FileSystem I use to create the tree class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileSystem {
private Directory root;
private Directory wDir;
private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

// Constructor
public FileSystem() {

}

// Constructor with parameters
public FileSystem(Directory root) {
    this.root = root;
    wDir = root;
    files.add(root);
}

// Returns the FileSystem's files
public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

// Returns the working directory
public Directory getWDir() {
    return wDir;
}

// Sets the working directory
public void setWDir(Directory d) {
    wDir = d;
}

// Returns the root file. This will always be / in our program
public File getRoot() {
    return root;
}

// Find any file by name
File findFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.getName().equals(name))
        return f;
    File file = null;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            file = findFile(c, name);
            if (file != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

// Returns true if file is found
boolean isFile(String name) {
    File file = null;
    file = findFile(root, name);
    if (file != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Creates Directory
public void mkdir(String path) {
    files.add(new Directory(path));

    int size = files.size();

    // Sets the parent
    files.get(size - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Sets the child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(size - 1));
}

// Changes working directory
public void cd(String s) {
    if (s.equals("..")) {
        if (wDir != root) {
            wDir = wDir.getParent();
        }
    } else {
        wDir = (Directory) findFile(root, s);
    }

}

// Provides absolute filename
public void pwd() {
    if (wDir == root) {
        System.out.println("/");
    } else {
        System.out.println(wDir.getPath());
    }
}

// Lists children of current working directory
public void ls() {
    ArrayList<File> children = wDir.getChildren();
    if (children != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            String childName = children.get(i).getName();
            System.out.print(childName + " ");
        }
    }
}

// Lists children of file(s) inputted by user
public void ls(File f) {
    String name = f.getName();
    if (f instanceof TextFile) {
        System.out.println("TextFile " + name + ":");
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
    } else {
        ArrayList<File> children = ((Directory) f).getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + name + ":");
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                String childName = children.get(i).getName();
                System.out.print(childName + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}

// Creates a TextFile or edit's TextFile's content if already exists in the
// tree
public void edit(String name, String content) {
    files.add(new TextFile(name, content));

    // Setting TextFile parent
    files.get(files.size() - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Setting Parent's child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(files.size() - 1));

}

// Prints the content of TextFile
public void cat(String name) {
    File f = findFile(root, name);
    System.out.println(((TextFile) f).getContent());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the semantics correctly, findFile is not the correct way to traverse the tree to the destination. You have to traverse the tree path-segment by path-segment, so that the tree-level is in sync with the level of the path-element in the filename.

Otherwise you look up names deeper in the filesystem, when you actually should only look for it in the current level.

However, I cannot provide a code example without knowing the interface of implementation of "tree".

EDIT: Provide example to illustrate the idea

```
// Todo: Set tree to root if filename starts with /

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    File f = tree.getFile(dirSplit[i]);
    if (f == null) {
        tree.mkdir(dirSplit[i]);
        f = tree.getFile(dirSplit[i]);
    }
    // Todo: Handle f not instance of Directory
    tree.setWDir((Directory) f);
   }
```

}

You need an implementation of getFile too:

```
File getFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            if (c.getName().equals(name))
                return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do you get the idea?

Comment: +1 to showing us what the `Tree` class is doing.  Without a complete code sample, it's really hard to say for sure what's going on.

Comment: I've edited the main post to include my `FileSystem` class. @Ctx @DanO

Comment: I added an example of the idea how to handle this

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. I believe I got it working. In the `for loop` you provided, I used `tree.getWDir()` as my `File f` condition for `getFile(File f, String name)`. And after the for loop was complete I reset my `wDir` by keeping the `tree.setWDir(saveWDir)`. Is that correct? Also should I use this `getFile` method always throughout the rest of my program, instead of using the `findFile` method? @Ctx

Comment: Yes. Of course, you could also change the interface to pass the directory to look for to the getFile-Method and do not change the working directory at all. Whatever looks cleaner to you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. So instead of having `File f = tree.getFile(tree.getWDir(),dirSplit[i]);`, and `f = tree.getFile(dirSplit[i]);` in my for loop, it would be what?

Comment: No, I thought about introducing a variable curDir, initialized with "root", and using this with tree.getFile(curDir, ...). Instead of setWDir(f), you would just say "curDir = f" then.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes sense now. I really appreciate the help. One last question, should I get rid of my `findFile` method now that I have `getFile`?

Comment: Depends, maybe you need this function in the future for some other purpose? I wouldn't hurry deleting it, since it exists now.